# Appium Automation - Method has not yet been implemented

Tags: android, selenium, appium, ios-ui-automation

I'm trying to explore Mobile App Automation, i'm running into this issue.

```js
package sample;
import java.io.File;
    import java.net.MalformedURLException;
    import java.net.URL;
    import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;

import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
    public class AndroidTest {  
        static WebDriver driver;
        public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException, InterruptedException 
        {
            File app= new File("C:\\Users\\ASSOUND\\Downloads\\DevOps\\mymbfs60_simulator_0301.apk");
            DesiredCapabilities capabilities= new DesiredCapabilities();
            capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "Android Emulator");
            capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
            capabilities.setCapability("app", app.getAbsolutePath());
            driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"),capabilities);
            driver.findElement(By.id("com.android.packageinstaller:id/permission_allow_button")).click();
            driver.quit();
            }
    }
```

This code Installs & Launches the App, but when i try to locate the Element and click, i'm getting this error:

> Exception in Thread "main" org.openga.selenium.WebDriverException: Method has not yet been implemented (WARNING: The server did not Provide..

Note: i tried to include enough time-wait before locating the element, but its still the same.

Comment: Instead of using WebDriver try using **AppiumDriver** or **AndroidDriver**

Comment: I tired both, and i'm still facing the same issue....

Comment: Show your updated code.  You were getting the error because you were using a standard web driver but trying to access a native mobile app.  A correct implementation of an Appium or Android driver should have corrected your issue, but you need to show how you did it, especially if you're saying it didn't work.

Comment: i didnt make any changes to above code, i tried with different combinations of drivers, 

"sorry, i'm unable to paste the code again here",